# How to access Jenkins remotely on Ubuntu 12.04 server?

Tags: jenkins

I have installed Jenkins and opened port 8080 on Ubuntu 12.04 server but still can't access Jenkins remotely. Below is the procedures I took.

```
# Install Jenkins, enable UFW and open port 8080
sudo apt-get install jenkins
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow 8080
sudo ufw reload

# Check the status
sudo ufw status
8080    ALLOW    Anywhere
8080    ALLOW    Anywhere (v6)

# Locally
curl -I localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10
...

# On an external machine
curl -I [ip]:8080
couldn't connect to host
```

Comment: Perhaps Jenkins is only listening on localhost.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue which was resolved by editing jenkins config file

> sudo vim /etc/default/jenkins

edit HTTP_HOST, default 127.0.0.1 to

> HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0

Comment: I don't even have **HTTP_HOST** in my file.  How did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Add JENKINS_ARGS

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--prefix=/jenkins --httpListenAddress=YOUR_IP --ajp13ListenAddress=YOUR_IP"
```

on Centos/Redhat, you can find on /etc/sysconfig/jenkins.

Comment: On Ubuntu it's `/etc/default/jenkins`.

Comment: Tried internal and external ip addresses and still nothing. When I add the ip args I can no longer access jenkins locally.

Comment: I will probably end up setting up projects on my desktop installation and exporting them to the server installation -- is this the usually process -- im new to jenkins?

Comment: after you add the JENKINS_ARGS, are you able to see the --httpListenAddress on your process list (ps aux|grep jenkins) ?                           or if you can find jenkins.war, just running it manually (java -jar jenkins.war -httpListenAddress=YOUR_IP)

Comment: @Rikih -- yup its in the output for `sudo ps aux | grep jenkins` -- but still cant access jenkins remotely

Comment: netstat | grep JENKINS_PORT, if it's listen on IP:JENKINS_PORT, mean firewall on your server/network. flush the firewall for test. if it's working mean the firewall rule else check firewall on network

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue which was resolved by adding 8080 port access to the uft firewall.

sudo ufw allow 8080

Answer (score 0):

Check if apparmor
 is running on your Ubuntu , may be apparmor blocking it, if its running stop 
it.

Answer (score 0):

What firewall are you using? If you are using iptables then run sudo iptables -L to see which ports are opened/blocked.